# Split column using regular expressions in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

Im trying so split column in my dataframe into two columns. Values in column look like this:

```
column
user_author-5
creator-user-5
```

Desired result is this:

```
column            number
user_author         5
creator-user        7
```

I do this:

```
df %>%  
  tidyr::extract(col = "column", 
                 into = c("number"), 
                 regex = "-(\\d+)$", 
                 remove = FALSE
                 )
```

But i get this:

```
column            number
user_author-5       5
creator-user-7      7
```

How could i split column and remove that number from the first column at the same time? The problem here is that there are some "-" in text too, so I must use regular expression "-(\d+)$", not "-". It makes it a little bit unclear to me

Comment: `tidyr::separate(df, column,into = c('column', 'number'), sep = '-', convert = TRUE)`

Comment: @RonakShah The problem here is that there are some "-" in text too, so I must use regular expression "-(\d+)$", not "-". It makes it a little bit unclear to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extract` like :

```
tidyr::extract(df, column, c('column', 'number'), '(.*)-.*?(\\d+)')
#        column number
#1  user_author      5
#2 creator-user      7
```

in regex we capture data in two groups. First group is till first `'-'` and the second group is the last number.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(column = c("user_author-5", "creator-user-7")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: but i want value in column "creator-user" not "creator". so it still separates text too. that was the unclear part

Comment: `tidyr::extract(df, column, c('column', 'number'), '(.*)-.*(\\d+)')`

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try in this case.

```
library(stringr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(colum2 = str_extract_all(column, regex("(?<=-)\\d{1,}$")))
#           column colum2
# 1  user_author-5      5
# 2 creator-user-7      7
```